# Update multiple values with same id using php

Tags: php

I'm trying to change my values in database.. In my database it saved like this

```
ID                  COLOR
1                    RED
1                    BLUE
1                    GREEN
```

I want to update all id which is 1 in my color category

Now i want to update it like this

```
 Color1 : RED  to BLACK
 Color2 : BLUE to YELLOW
 Color3: GREEN To WHITE
```

But when i click update.. The result become like this

```
Color1 : WHITE 
Color2 : WHITE
Color3:  WHITE
```

How am i able to save the fix that?

Here's my code.

HTML FORM

```
<div class='control-group'>
   <div style='margin-left: 25px; margin-top:-5px;'>
    <label style='display: inline-block !important; vertical-align: middle; float: left; font-weight: bold; margin-left:40px;'> Color Combination $x &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>

   <div class='controls'>
   <select name='color1[]' class='form-control'  id='color1' onchange='getcolor()'><option value=''>$test</option>
    ";

 $statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM color order by colorName ASC");
   $statement->execute();

     while($rows = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
echo "<option value='" .$rows['colorName']. "'>" . $rows['colorName'] . " - " . $rows['colorCode'] ."</option>";
        }

echo "</select>";
```

MY SUBMIT CODES

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$color1 = $_POST['color1'];
$count = count($color1);

 for ($x = 0; $x <=$count; $x++) {

    if($color2[$x] == "")
    {   
     $savecolor = $color1[$x];

$stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE productcolor set colorName = :color WHERE productinformationID=:productinformationID');
$stmt->execute(array(':color' => $savecolor, ':productinformationID' => $prodID));
    }
}   

}
```

But when i echo  $savecolor = $color1[$x]; it display the color that i chose but when it comes in saving its not..

Comment: For same ID, you should find something which is unique to update, in your case only way -> Color. So add color too in where condition

Comment: should have any unique column in database to update the value

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41833172/update-multiple-author-in-php-but-not-same-value/41833897#41833897

Answer (score 1):

You will need `AND` condition to specify which color should be updated.

For example:

```
UPDATE productcolor
SET colorName = :color
WHERE productinformationID=:productinformationID
AND colorName = :colorName
```

`:colorName` should be the color to be changed.

Comment: Can you post how did you implement?

Comment: I have a question.. In colorname in where condition where should i get the colorname it is in the display color right? something like this $color1 = $row['colorName'] ? Am i right?

Comment: Yes. It should be old color value. You have to post the old color value as well.

Comment: This is how i do it..   $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE productcolor
SET colorName = :color
WHERE colorName = :colorName AND productinformationID=:productinformationID
');
    $stmt->execute(array(':color' => $savecolor, ':colorName' => $test, ':productinformationID' => $prodID));  Still same result

Comment: Value in `$test` should be old color. Did you print `$test`? How did you get it?

Comment: Yes it print the old color.. But when saving still same result

Comment: Lets modify your code a bit. Add `echo '<input type="hidden" name="originalColor" value="'.$test.'"/>';` in your HTML after `select` closing tag. On submit code, use `$_POST['originalColor']`.

Comment: Same result. My only problem is my update. $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE productcolor SET colorName = :color
 WHERE productinformationID=:productinformationID');
 $stmt->execute(array(':color' => $savecolor,':productinformationID' => $prodID)); If ever i will use the $test as my old color how will i enter the test in my full update codes?

Comment: Your problem isn't clear. If you POST `originalColor` as `red` and new color is `black`, then $_POST['originalColor'] should have value as `red`. Then you can update it using the query you posted in comment above. $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE productcolor SET colorName = :color WHERE colorName = :colorName AND productinformationID=:productinformationID '); $stmt->execute(array(':color' => $savecolor, ':colorName' => $_POST['originalColor'], ':productinformationID' => $prodID));